# Instantiation of Elasticsearch client in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using a Nodejs app with npm module- elasticsearch. 
Should I instantiate Elasticsearch client every time I make a call to an ES API or should I create only 1 instance of ES client and use it for every request or should I use a mix of the above and what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

I create a client for every call (or several calls) because I have to close the client explicitly because else my node program won't end.